# Displaying a div inside an another one

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div which has overflow:hidden. Inside a parent div, there is a dynamic div which height is more than the height of the parent div. How can I make the child div to be displayed as it is? Now it will be clipped because of the height of the parent div. I do not want to allow scrollbars to be displayed.

```
<div style="width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; background-color: transparent; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="width:100%;top:5px;left:150px;position:absolute;z-index:5000;background-color:#323B5A;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.85);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.85);box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.85);">
    sgssgsgsgsdgsdgsgsg<br>aafafafafa<br>sgggdgdsgsgsdgdg
  </div>
</div>
```

**Update**

It seems to me that this would work just fine. But I do not want to use position:relative with the child div.

```
<div style="width: 10000em; margin-left: -5000em; position: relative; left: 50%; text-align: center; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto; margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 0; background-color: transparent; overflow:hidden;">
  <div style="width:100%;top:5px;left:150px;position:relative;z-index:5000;background-color:#323B5A;-webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.85);-moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.85);box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 5px rgba(255,255,255,0.85);">
    sgssgsgsgsdgsdgsgsg<br>aafafafafa<br>sgggdgdsgsgsdgdg
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: You can't have your cake and eat it. Decide which you want, the overflow:hidden or not :)

Comment: Overflow-y:visible did not work.

Comment: provide a working example

Comment: If the inner div is non-dynamic, it will be displayed correctly. But when it is dynamic, it will be clipped.

Comment: Still, provide a working example :)

Comment: Can we see your code?

Comment: just give the height of parent div to 100%. Hope it will work

Answer (score 0):

You could add a position:absolute to take the inner div out of the flow.

Answer (score 0):

If you take the child div out of flow, using position fixed or absolute, than it would be visible. But please note: the parent div must remain static:

```css
.holder {
    position: relative;
}
.parent {
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
.child {
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="holder">
    <div class="parent">
        <div class="child">Visible?</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Also on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6re4fmas/).

Comment: As said earlier: If the inner div is non-dynamic, it will be displayed correctly. But when it is dynamic, it will be clipped.

Comment: That is [not true](https://jsfiddle.net/6re4fmas/1/), just **remove** relative position from parent div.

Comment: Please note that I have updated my question. Please also note that I cannot say the height of the parent div.

Comment: Maybe better tell us what is your goal, what you want to achieve with those negative margins on parent div. Can you find a similar example on net?